# Check after Copying

Tags: command-line, partitioning

Sometimes I copy a lot of data using the

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

command. Recently, that copying made a bug that I have found only accidentally. Which command should I use to compare the original and the copy? The

```
info diff
```

apparently does not show that such sort of parameters can be used with the diff command.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29921/comparison-of-raw-block-devices Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks; I use such a copying only to a disk of the same type, brand and therefore size.

Answer (score 2):

assuming source and destination drives are identical size, compare md5sum of source and destination.

```
md5sum /dev/source
md5sum /dev/dest
```

this should also work if destination is an image file.

If physical destination drive is larger than physical source drive (or file), you'll need to request MD5SUM of the destination, selecting the same number of blocks as copied.

```
dd if=/dev/dest bs=n count=n | md5sum
```